# Собственные лайки на странице

Tags: php

Делаю я значит на сайте раздел статей, которые имеют заголовок, текст, изображения и комментарии пользователей. Хотелось бы добавить еще ко всему вышеперечисленному лайки статей, чтобы пользователи могли без комментариев просто лайкать статьи. Подсчет идет лайков от уникальных пользователей. Как это можно сделать? Натолкните на мысль... Есть картинка наверное в виде сердца и счетчик рядом с ней. По нажатию на картинку должен срабатывать код, который берет ip-адрес пользователя и плюсовать к счетчику значение одно. Записывает лайк в базу данных и сменяет картинку лайка на нажатый. Так мыслю? Как на практике такое реализовать?

[image]

Comment: "собственные лайки", - это всмысле вконтакте?

Comment: нет свои собственные лайки, как в контакте например или как на хэшкоде том же, где статья каждая оценивается положительно или отрицательно.

Comment: у вас тоже интернет слабый и потому до поиска, как из села Ломоносова до Москвы?

Comment: ну я в гугле пробовал искать "создание собственных лайков", а там больше попадались статьи, как подлючить лайки от социальных сетей, а не свои собственные...

Comment: посоветуйте может плагины какие-то по созданию лайков... Не знаю как лайки назвать по другому, англоязычный компонент.

Comment: попробуйте так : рейтинг своими руками

Comment: ну на одном php - это можно сделать? Проблема в том, что я javascript, jQuery Не знаю еще...((

Comment: советую почитать вот [это][1]

[1]:http://irbis-team.com/?PHPSESSID=efdd9ea66cf25bd5ce4ffc2b8f3da4cc

Comment: Не знаю, поможет ли, но я посоветовал бы копать не в сторону лайков, а в сторону систем для голосований. Тема вроде как более популярная и исходников должно быть больше, а по факту, то же самое, что и лайки. Фиксировать по IP, по ID пользователя, по MAC адресу - это уже зависит исключительно от того, какая аудитория должна ставить лайки: гости, зарегистрированные и т.д., в зависимости от спецификации Вашего сервиса

Answer (score 2):

создайте таблицу где id article_id ip и при при лайке проверяйте если данный ip есть в базе с этой статьей то не добавляется лайк или выводиться значек сразу что вы уже лайкнули. Количество лайков считается по количеству записей для данной статьи. Можно привязывать вместо ip хеш IP+браузер или через куку... дело техники.. но однозначно AJAX... И еще не используйте таблицу для лафков типа InnoDB так как она блокируеться при записи и если чисто теоретически кто то счелкнит на разных компах в один и тот же момент то засчитывается только один.. как то так..во общем..

Comment: спасибо, плюсанул твой ответ. Я примерно так и мыслил на этот счет. Но проблема в том, что я AJAX не знаю. На одном php можно такое реализовать?

Comment: можно, но с перезагрузкой страницы. без перезагрузки только AJAX. Подучи эту технологию. Она не нстолько сложная как кажется

Comment: AJAX очень простой если знаете jquery то это еще легче.

Comment: @ukroficer, а как быть, если IP динамический?

Answer (score 1):

Сам уже как то реализовывал такой принцип: При лайке ты записываешь в базу ник или id зарегистрированного пользователя. То есть в одном месте привязанном к конкретной статье ты сохраняешь ники через разделитель (например #). Ты знаешь кто конкретно лайкал и сколько их. Естественно перед сохранением нужно проверить на наличие. Даже можно уже на странице иметь готовый масив ников.

А про ajax+jQuery: разобраться 15 минутное дело! Возмись и через 15мин (максимум 30мин) ты будешь все знать! Сейчас без этого трудно, шагните из прошлого века.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Правда у меня нету ников, потому придется через ip-адреса сохранять пользователей уникальных. Насчет ajax и jQuery обнадежили, я думал там сложно)).

Comment: Вы наверное удивитесь, но лучше создать отдельную таблицу голосов и по ней считать рейтинг. Плюс в том, что можно будет обойтись без сериализованых массивов(или, как Вы писали: "через разделитель.." )

Comment: http://anton.shevchuk.name/jquery-book/

Comment: спасибо за статью)