# Как реализовать лайки?

Tags: javascript, php

Возможно ли реализовать лайки на php и js, именно реализацию через php, а изменение лайка на активный, через js.
также должно выводится кол-во лайков, которое вытягивается из БД
Если возможно, то как?

Comment: "Если возможно, то как" --- почитать книги по php, js, БД, хотя бы основы и написать код

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Собственные лайки на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/237875/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

1. Делаешь запрос с js на php, он берет из бд кол-во лайков. А также если нужно, то еще и смотришь ставил ли этот пользователь лайк
2. В js получаешь это кол-во лайков, вставляешь куда нужно. Проверяешь есть лайк от этого пользователя
3. в js вешаешь onclick на кнопку лайка, по нажатию проверяешь, нужно ли удалить или поставить лайк
4. отправляешь запрос на сервер, чтобы он увеличил (или уменьшил) кол-во лайков, так же помечаешь, что пользователь поставил лайк